# Custom WP rest api endpoint only working on non https?

Tags: ajax, jquery, rest-api, endpoints

I'm **googling like an hour** for a possible solution while im trying to **create my first custom** wordpress rest api endpoint.

**If** i call the endpoint **by postman** it just **works**, but **if i try with jquery**, it doesn't.

I noticed, that **if** i call it by the **http version it works**, but on https it just returns 404?

Heres my endpoint registration:

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route('the-namespace/v1', '/the-endpoint', [
    'method' => WP_REST_Server::CREATABLE,
    'callback' => 'theEndpoint',
    'permission_callback' => function () {
      return true;
    }
  ]);
});

function theEndpoint(WP_REST_Request $request)
{
  $data = [
    'some' => 'data',
  ];

  $res = new WP_REST_Response($data);
  $res->set_status(200);

  return [$res];
}
```

And the corresponding js ajax code:

```
var data = {
  unusedData: 'so far',
};
jQuery.ajax({
  method: 'POST',
  url: '/wp-json/the-namespace/v1/the-endpoint',
  data: data,
  dataType: 'json',
  contentType: 'applcation/json',
  success: function(data, status) {
    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
  }
})
```

Sure i googled and tried to compare what postman is doing differently, but maybe i'm overlooking something?

Thanks for your time!

**EDIT - more info:**

- Permalinks have been flushed
- Site (Wordpress Adress and Site Adress) is configured HTTPS
- It's the full example code
- I noticed, that i can actually register the same thing as get and it works. Only the post style registration doesnt work.

**EDIT - htaccess (not from me..)**
I just created a link to view the htaccess file, I don't know if it's too big for here, so i pasted it on pastebin - [here](https://pastebin.com/9eet8MVZ).

Comment: did you flush/resave permalinks after adding the endpoint? Nothing about what you've shared would cause a difference between http and https. What is your endpoint meant to do? Are you loading the site in the browser via http or https?

Comment: @TomJNowell I will Google that flush thingy, but i actually think if this would be the case, the link shouldn't work (in postman/at all). No i'm not using the "browser" like with a get request visiting that endpoint. I'm calling the jquery Script to make the request or tested with postman. EDIT: Tried flushing permalinks with going into settings->permalinks and saving the settings.

Comment: literally go to the permalinks settings page and click save. I ask because the page you are running that code on may or may not have been served over https and that is significant as it could result in mixed http/https errors. That your server is able to respond on HTTP without redirecting to HTTPS is itself problematic, it should not be possible to make this request using HTTP only as HTTP is a security hazard. A well configured server would redirect to the HTTPS version.

Comment: Also is this the full code, or just an equivalent generic version you wrote to hide your actual code and just show only what you thought was relevant? Because if there were permissions logic then that might explain some of this, but none is present in what you've shared

Comment: @TomJNowell It's the exact code just for testing purposes. If I visit my domain/homepage via http it get's redirected to https. PS: Yeah, Chrome blocks this request when i'm like trying to supply the http equivalent just for like testing, but as this is expected, this is not a/the problem, so i'm not confused as this my expected behaviour. I can only test by postman with http only.

Comment: and your site is configured to believe it lives at a https address? I notice your jQuery AJAX only has a success function but no failure function, and you've not shared the response data which can contain valuable information

Comment: @TomJNowell I will check that, but i should be configured as https-only site. I didn't implement any failure function, because I'm inspecting the data coming back from the network tab inside the developer tools. PS: But as i can see your replies, there shouldn't be something importantly wrong on what i've provided.